# Does desiredAccuracy affect region monitoring?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, geofencing

Does `DesiredAccuracy` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/desiredAccuracy) affect region monitoring ? My guess is that it just affects location updates, but I want to be sure. Apple documentation doesn't specifically say anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't affect region monitoring.
But a delay may be observed based on which source the framework fetched the location updates.

Setting a desiredAccuracy property will enable LocationFramework to provide you location updates & significant location changes based on the property.  If you choose it to be a value "best", the framework will take care of sending location updates as per that value, depending on the location updates being fetched from either wifi, or cellular or GPS.
If you set it to "navigation", you will get location updates from all the possible ways the framework can detect the location changes.

Hope that helps.